# Cannot combine a city airport with existing station but can do with small airport

Tags: openttd

I have a station where there is a bus stop, truck stop and a harbour all combined together. Now I like to add a city airport. But I cannot combine the city airport with the existing station. When I choose a small airfield instead, I can combine this with the existing station. Is there any reason for this? Am I doing something wrong? Or may this be a bug or some game limitation?

Combining OK:
[image: The airfield I can combine with the existing station]

Combining not possible:
[image: The airport I cannot combine]

Comment: Are you placing the airport adjacent to the existing station, or are you trying to place the airport while holding ctrl?

Comment: I am trying while holding ctrl.

Comment: Does the existing station just not show up in the list that pops up?

Comment: Adding a screenshot of your situation would help a lot!

Comment: @MMM Yes, it does not show up in the list. Screenshots added. Thanks.

Comment: @MMM Thank you, answer accepted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129510/discussion-between-this-myself-and-mmm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to extend the station beyond the maximum set station spread size. The small airport still fits within this limit (which is 12x12 tiles by default) but since the city airport is much bigger it most likely extends beyond the limit.

You can change this by increasing the station spread size in your settings:
[image]

Comment: The AI doesn't do this, so the larger you allow the spread, the bigger advantage you give yourself. If you don't care about that though, making it huge will allow you to create to giant stations that covers half the map and you simply ship between the two, making all the money.